# Is there a better term for a male pig [literal sense--the animal] than "boar"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I googled `male pig word` and got results that said the word was *boar.* I thought, "That's odd; I thought that was the word for a *wild* pig!" So I visited [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boar?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) and sure enough, it has both meanings:

> boar [bawr, bohr]
>   noun
>   1. the uncastrated male swine.
>   2. wild boar.
>   adjective
>   3. South Midland and Southern U.S. (of animals) male, especially full-grown: a boar cat.

So I was wondering, since there exists a term that *only* means *female pig--sow,* does such a word exist that *only* means *male pig* and nothing else? I'm looking for a unique term.

Comment: There is hardly any word at all that means only one thing....

Comment: @Hellion Considering that there are [numerous distinct words for cattle](http://www.wikihow.com/Tell-the-Difference-Between-Bulls,-Cows,-Steers-and-Heifers), it's a pretty reasonable question.

Comment: Boar is a perfectly acceptable term for a male domestic swine.  That's why wild boar is always termed *wild*.  Otherwise, it would just say boar.

Comment: Fun fact: a sow can also be a female of several other land mammal species, including bears and badgers.

Comment: Are there also "wild sows"?  There must be; I assume not all wild boars are escapees from captivity.

Comment: @G I think in context of _wild_ boar it refers to either sex, male or female. [See this definition.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wild+boar?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)

Comment: I think it is confusing. As a pig farmer, I was hoping to find better words, obscure words. Etc. I am left with genus terms like Sus , Suidae Family, Suids , and over 19 genus nouns that I will try to somehow use. Then there is the word ungulate. I may attempt to proliferate my own terms. Ex: ungulato = an adult male pig. I say , make up a term and use it until it gets entered into the dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

There are three terms used for this purpose. Here's a description of all three from Wikipedia.

1. Boar or hog, male pig of breeding age.
2. Barrow, male pig castrated before puberty.
3. Stag, male pig castrated later in life (an older boar after castration).

Comment: So there's no term that can't be confused with _wild_ boar? That's disappointing!

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink Context matters. And in most case it's context that clears up the confusion.

Comment: A note on "stag", since it's [not the common usage of the word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stag):  When used in this context, it means _any_ animal that was castrated after reaching sexual maturity, or cattle or sheep castrated before sexual maturity.

Answer (score 3):

> If the species is called "*hog*" (AmE), the name for a full grown male hog is "**boar**", and "pig" for a young, weaned hog or any immature hog, and a "piglet" for a little pig, especially a suckling one.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pig

> If the species is called "*pig*" (chiefly BE) or "*swine*", the name for a mature male pig is "**hog**", "shoat/shote" for a young, weaned pig or any immature pig, and "piglet" for a young, unweaned pig.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shoat

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/piglet

Comment: Not to be confused with hogg, hug or ugg which colloquially means sheep in parts of Scotland and Cornwall.

Comment: Your answer gives several _specialized_ names unique to various stages of development. Perhaps I should clarify that I seek a unique term for the _adult male_ pig, and it pains me that its name is so easily confused with _a wild swine, regardless of gender._

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink The thing is a wild boar can also be referred to as a wild hog or a wild pig http://m.myfwc.com/wildlifehabitats/profiles/mammals/land/wild-hog/

Comment: I only care about the ambiguity of the word _boar._

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the question is much more difficult than it may at first appear, as there are multiple names for male, female and even hermaphrodite pigs. These names take into account, among other things, age, weight, sexual maturity, “sexual degrees” (such as whether the males have been castrated, when there is only one testicle “showing,” or for hermaphroditic ones). For a good account of these multiple swine names and their meanings, see *Rare Breed Pig Keeping*, p. 54 (available online at http://www.gospbc.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/RareBreedPigKeeping.pdf

Therefore there does not seem to be a single name for either a female or male pig, but several to choose from based on a wide variety of differences.